# Treat elements with different attributes differently in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I am writing a specialization for a pre-defined XML format. I would like to allow this:

```
<InterfaceClass Name="Program">
    <InterfaceClass Name="ProgramPart" />
</InterfaceClass>
```

while not allowing that:

```
<InterfaceClass Name="ProgramPart" />
```

meaning ProgramParts may only occur under Program elements.

I would like also to ignore everything else in the XML file, since I have a schema for the general format.

Is it possible? Or is there any other formalism suitable for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSD 1.1 allows you to do this with the facility called "Conditional Type Assignment" - you can write an element declaration in which a number of alternative types are given, selected according to the value of the element's attributes. There's no equivalent in XSD 1.0. XSD 1.1 is currently implemented in Saxon and Xerces.